# Laravel 4.1, changing auth.model works, but L4 502s if you remove the models/User.php file

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

The default Authentication model is `app/models/User.php`, set by the config item `auth.model`
That worked fine. So of course I decided to follow a nice guide a make my own namespaced directory to keep all of my models, repos, etc.

I added the line to composer.json to autoload, changed the `auth.model` setting to the path (model namespace is `Models\User`), but upon removing the `models/user.php` file, L4 kicks out a 502 with the (very brief) log entry of

> ...FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'User' not found' 
>          in .../Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:711

If I add back the `models/User.php` file, everything works, except it uses the wrong model to log in, so I have to keep a copy in each place.

Am I missing something, some other setting? I can't imagine the path to the User model is hard-coded, but it's sure acting that way.

This is with a fairly fresh Homestead install with Vagrant.

**Update #1**

Relevant lines from composer.json

```
"autoload": {
"classmap": [
"app/EC"
```

Snippet of User class. They're the standard boilerplate User models, except I extend Eloquent with my ECBaseModel class, so the one in `app/models` extends `\Models\ECBaseModel` instead

```
<?php namespace Models;  
use \Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use \Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
class User extends ECBaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    getAuthIdentifier, getAuthPassword, getReminderEmail, getRememberTokens
}
```

**Updated #2**

`[2014-07-01 20:04:09] homestead.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'User' not found' in /home/vagrant/Code/ec_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:711`
`Stack trace:`
`#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()`
`#1 {main} [] []`

Comment: i assume you already did a `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Oh yea, I've `dump-autoload`ed, `install`ed, `update`ed probably a hundred times today. Doesn't give me any errors during that part, and I can `dd()` before the auth filters fire to avoid the 502 (so I knew at least it wasn't nginx or something structural)

Comment: mind posting your `Models\User` class? how does the autoload bit look like in your composer.json?

Comment: Added snippets. Only non-standard thing is extending a class that extends Eloquent (except of course for moving it into a different dir)

Comment: It *does* seem to be actually using my `Models\User` for auth, but if I remove the `app/models/user.php` file it errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people have suggested dump-autoload but that cannot be the case. PHP knows that it wants to talk to the `User` class and is failing to find it, but as it does not exist then running dump-autoload is not going to help. It would help only if PHP knew it wanted to talk to `Models\User` but could not find it, as the autoload lookup was old.

Paste in the entire backtrace. The error will be in there. It will tell us what code is actually calling this old reference. When you see what is trying to call it, you can kill it.

Update: PSR-4 is a little better at handling autoloading when it comes to namespaces.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/src/"
    }
},
```

Then have `app/src/Model/User.php` and put it in the `App\Model` namespace, calling it `User`.

Comment: Added. There really wasn't much given, part of the frustrating thing about the error.

Comment: Oh! You're using classmap and throwing namespaces and folders at it. I'd suggest you use PSR-0 or PSR-4 to autoload your code. Updating answer.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a shot in a few